# How to extract the origen_testers test names in hierarchial order based on the AST?

Tags: origen-sdk

We use n external binning rules engine vs using the Native binning API in `origen_testers` and need to pass it a list of the test names in the proper order.  The issue arises when we use `on_fail` or `on_pass` flow arguments that contain `procs`.  These child tests can contain several layers of similar `proc` calls.  The child tests are processed first before the parent tests so the binning order gets reversed.  Is there a way to extract a list of test names that preserves the parent to child relationship?  I know `flow.atp.raw` shows the hierarchy.

[image]

How can I select out the TestSuite names in the proper order?

thx

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the ATP:

```
s(:test,
s(:object, <TestSuite: jtag_ccra_all_vmin>),
s(:name, "jtag_ccra_all_vmin"),
s(:number, 0),
s(:id, "jtag_ccra_all_vmin"),
s(:on_fail,
  s(:if_flag, "$Alarm",
    s(:render, "multi_bin;")),
  s(:test,
    s(:object, <TestSuite: jtag_ccra_top_vmin>),
    s(:name, "jtag_ccra_top_vmin"),
    s(:number, 0),
    s(:id, "jtag_ccra_top_vmin"),
    s(:on_fail,
      s(:if_flag, "$Alarm",
        s(:render, "multi_bin;")))),
  s(:test,
    s(:object, <TestSuite: jtag_ccra_gasket_vmin>),
    s(:name, "jtag_ccra_gasket_vmin"),
    s(:number, 0),
    s(:id, "jtag_ccra_gasket_vmin"),
    s(:on_fail,
```

I am wondering if there is way to extract the names in order:

```
['jtag_ccra_all_vmin', 'jtag_ccra_top_vmin', 'jtag_ccra_gasket_vmin']
```

`flow.atp.raw.children` returns them in order as an Array but I would like to just query out the `name` attribute versus the ATP node objects.

thx

Comment: Don't really understand the question, can you elaborate with an example of an AST and the corresponding output you want to produce from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to extract information from the AST is to make a processor, something like this: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/atp/processors/extract_set_flags.rb

In your processor you would make a method called `on_test` and then from there you can extract the name.
This is untested, but something like this:

```rb
class ExtractTestNames < OrigenTesters::ATP::Processor
  def run(node)
    @results = []
    process(node)
    @results
  end

  # All 'test' nodes in the AST will be handed to this method, all nodes which don't have
  # a specific handler defined will pick up a default handler which simply processes
  # (looks for a handler for) all of the node's children
  def on_test(node)
    @results << node.find(:name).value
    # Keep processing the children of this node, so that any tests embedded
    # in on_fail nodes, etc. are picked up
    process_all(node.children)
  end
end
```

To call it:

```rb
ExtractTestNames.new.run(flow.atp.raw)  # => ['jtag_ccra_all_vmin', 'jtag_ccra_top_vmin', ...]
```